# Vertically align an input?

Tags: html, css, alignment

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wb1fp7r/)

I need to vertically align an input in it's parent, along with it's label.

I have tried the table cell method but no luck:

```
<div class="holder">
    <label>Text input: </label>
    <input type="text" class="input" /> 
</div>

.holder{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: tomato;
    display: table;
}

.input{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for table layout since container has fixed height, use `line-height` property instead for your `.holder` element:

```
line-height:400px;
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2wb1fp7r/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Make `.holder` the table cell.

```
.holder{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: tomato;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

.input{
    /* remove the styles */
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wb1fp7r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `line-height` property on the parent. Set it to `400px` will make all content vertically aligned.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/xhg15p5L/